# Sending pageType and pageName to DataLayer

Tags: google-analytics, typo3, universal-analytics, google-datalayer, data-layer

1. I would like to push

an **individual page name for every page** on my website (Home, Product Page Product A, Productpage Product B, Category Page Products A-C)

and a general category (Home, Category, Cart, Productpage)

into the DataLayer with pageName and pageCategory.

2. For now, we work with Typo3 and an extension from our tracking tool to name pages and categories individually.
3. We dislike this tracking tool and want to change to Google Analytics, so we would also get rid of the extension.

How is an individual page name and category usually set for every page? How to set and pull those two efficiently?

Comment: Anyone? It seems so simple but I cannot find anything on google.

Answer (score -1):

Each record is individually in TYPO3 as it is referenced with an `uid`.
Your pages have an `uid` and also your categories.

Also your pages can (should) be uniquely identified by the full path (URL). The same for categories: if you disentangle the tree you should get unique category-pathes.

So you can use the `uid`s you can't see the hierarchy in any analytics tool (or at least you need to add the hierarchy information).
If you use the pathes it should be possible to split/group the accesses in the same way as the hierarchy is given in the pathes.

Comment: Hi Bernd, 
many thanks for the answer!
So:
(1) Every page/link in Typo3 has a Unique ID
(2) I can see categories when going more to the top of the tree (one could be link "Babywear")
(3) I can push the URL to uniquely identify the page in the analytic tool. 
If I push the pagetitle in Typo3 as pageName to the analytics tool, some page titles might be duplicated. E.g. "Productinfo" might show up in different locations of the tree. 
If I want to push the Typo3 pagetitle as unique pageName, I need to give every page a unique pagetitle in the tree, next to uid. 

Does that sound right?

Comment: no. either you give the uid together with the name as reference to the analytic tool (`PAGE_<uid>-<title>`) theoretically you could use the uid alone (don't forget the table name!), but that would make the analysis more complicated. the other way: use the complete path and you have unique names: `furniture/livingroom/chairs` differs from `furniture/kitchen/chairs` and differs from `garden/chairs` so all three pages are named 'chairs'

Comment: thanks again! your option 2 makes sense not to have duplicates for pagenames. Do I need my developers to create a plugin where I can assign a unique name and category (for example "/furniture/kitchen/chairs") to every uid? 

To send it to the analytics tool, every page would need a declarative variable then (var pageName = ""; var pageCategory ="";)

Comment: depends, however you can do nearly everything with typoscript, but some problems can be solved cleaner with PHP. You could use the page URL (you may need to remove the domain). if you use ext:realurl it brings a field for individual pathes (pathsegment or full path) for each page. or you just concat page names of rootline. And all pages have a field for category assignment. so: no extra fields neccessary.